# Create SVG and save it to datastore(GAE + Python)

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i have a doubt, i need to create some svg files (in a sequence) and upload to data store. I know how to create the svg, but it save to filesystem, and i have understood that GAE cannot use it.

So, i don't know how to create and put it on the datastore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your "file" in memory (use e.g `io.BytesIO`) and then use the `getvalue` method of the in-memory "file" to get the blob of bytes for the datastore. *Do* note that a datastore entity is limited to a megabyte or so, thus it's quite possible that some SVG file might not fit in that space -- in which case, you should look into Google Cloud Storage. But, that's a different issue.

Comment: I never used io.BytesIO, but i can try use it. I have a question about limite size of entity: could i reference entity from blobstore with a entity from datastore?

Comment: @AntonioM, yes, a datastore entity holding metadata (a `BlobKeyProperty`, in `ndb`) referring to a blobstore entry is quite a classic arrangement. Personally, these days, I prefer to use Google Cloud Storage directly (again with metadata for a GCS object, such as path, size, etc, easily held in a datastore entity), so that `gcutil` and other approaches let me most easily check and maintain the GCS parts independently from GAE if and when I want to; and I suffer no 32 MB limit (which Blobstore does; GCS does *not*). But, if you like "retro" style, Blobstore works fine too!-)

Comment: I could use it, but i started using NDB for my final degree and i haven't enough time to migrate to GCS (and my first time with GAE). I will try to do with io.BytesIO tomorrow.

Comment: other doubt, how can I write the models and save svg? i am reading GAE docs and i don't understan the exactly form to do that. :S

Comment: You can have a "blob" ("just a bunch of bytes") as one of your model's properties -- e.g, an `ndb.BlobProperty` if you're using `ndb` (as you should if you're programming GAE with the Python 2.7 runtime). The 1MB limit for the whole entity remains, however!

Comment: BTW @AntonioM, assuming by your name you're Italian like me, is your "final degree" a Laurea Breve, Magistrale, or Dottorale? (In English terms, Bachelor, Master, or Doctor) -- just curious of course!

Comment: not, i am spanish, not italian ^^" Is a Degree. And i know that ndb have blobl property, but i refer how to save svg into blob store and then get key to put into a ndb model. When this is over I will have completed my final degree, but i don't understand how save data in blob store, because i think the image can be heavier than 1MB.

Comment: @AlexMartelli  just curios, why would you pick io.BytesIO over StringIO.  I hadn't even realized it existed and always used StringIO.

Comment: @TimHoffman i read that is recommended use BytesIO on python 2.7 and 3, but if i use it i get errors when i use image.write() of svgwrite. I must use StringIO, so, in this case, doesn't work with BytesIO. I will commento in few hours if finally work this or i must opt for other solutions.